# Python concatenate a string and a variable

Tags: string, python-2.7, variables, string-concatenation

I am trying to concatenate strings and variables , i see new lines get added ..

```
def convert_hostname(row_rack,ru_host,orig_hostname):
  if orig_hostname[0:9] == "ll21l01ms":
     print row_rack,
     print ru_host,
     temp_var = "ll21l01ls-" + row_rack + ru_host + ".com"
     print temp_var

Output when run :
0707
49
ll21l01ls-0707
49
.com
```

When i try to print the temp_var , it adds new lines during the concatenation.

The with output should be like this :

```
0707
49
ll21l01ls-070749.com
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It adds new lines, or it adds spaces where you don't want? If it is adding space you don't want, then .strip() the row_rack and ru_host to see if that works as there's no reason for it to add spaces when you concatenate the variables, unless the spaces are already there

Comment: Thanks! strip() worked!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
temp_var = "ll21l01ls-" + row_rack.strip() + ru_host.strip() + ".com"
```